# Global Assembly Cache - Assembly Install required

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I am currently updating a VB.NET application with Visual Studio 2013 that possibly was originally created on VS2010 or VS2012.

This application uses a Network SQL Database

Everything goes fine up to the point of installing when just shows an error message. that says the Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Shell.9.0' version 2.0.0.0
is required and then will not let me finish the installation.

The project has been exported using the Visual Basic tool [OneClick]

I have already checked the References list on the Project menu, and is not included there. Also not available to be added.

The project requires the Microsoft Framework 4.5, so it seems that the Shell v2.0.0.0 is pretty old...

Do you have any suggestions, this kept me scratching my head already quite a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
I am not too sure if this is the right solution or not but it worked for me. Hopefully this will help someone else.

It turn out to be a error with the framework I was compiling the project (v4.5), 
I was trying to install it on a Windows 7 machine with a framework installed up to v4.0. I cant understand why this error message showed up instead of telling me the framework version required for the software was not installed.

But anyways, I changed the version on the compiler, build and export again. Another error pop up but it was because references to the DLL for the different framework version were not included in the project. After including them and set the value for "Copy to Local" to true, the installation worked like a charm.

So I got my program up and working.